# How to import a large csv file(~4GB) to PostreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin-4

Currently, I am using PostgreSQL 11.2 and I have a ~4GB .csv file. Firstly I am trying to create a temporary table and select the needed columns to fill my current table.

```
create temporary table t (identification varchar, a1 text, a2 text, a3 text, a4 text, a15 text, a6 text, a7 text, a8 text)                       

copy t 
from 'C:\PostgreSqlData\mydata.csv'
delimiter ',' csv
```

If I get some smaller portion of data(~10MB), it does not give any errors. But, when I try to import the whole file, it gives:

> could not stat file "mydata.csv”: unknown error

Comment: are you trying to import it using command line ?

Comment: No, from pdAdmin4.

Comment: i think you hva to try it using command line

Comment: Thanks, but I am a beginner for PostgreSql, so I don't know how to run commands from commandline and which directory I will use to open the cmd.

Comment: which os you are using ?

Comment: Try running `select version();` to see if you're running a 32-bit or 64-bit version. 4 GB is right at the 32 bit size limit. Same for your Postgres client, which is I guess pgAdmin4.

Comment: Another possibility is [your anti-virus software is interfering by trying to scan the enormous file before you're allowed to copy it](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4B65A6E8.1080407%40kaltenbrunner.cc).

Comment: Finally, [this may be a bug in PostgreSQL 11.0](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/issues/493#issuecomment-435589201). Try upgrading to 11.2 or downgrading to 10.7.

Comment: Result for select version command: PostgreSQL 11.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

Answer (score 3):

- First check that  psql is already installed.
- Open your terminal
- Run the psql command :

*Try this way*

```
psql -c "COPY tablename FROM 'C:\PostgreSqlData\mydata.csv' delimiter ',' csv;"
```

Comment: which psql version you have ?

Comment: psql (PostgreSQL) 11.2

Comment: i found that is a bug in the PostgreSQL 11 , can you retry using version 10 .5

Comment: it just works but not data is imported into database